# Create zip style file without compression

Tags: c#

I know that there are many free and not so free compression libraries out there, but for the project i am working on, i need to be able to take file data from a stream and put it into some kind zip or pack file, but without compression, because i will need to access these files quickly without having to wait for them to decompress.

Anyone know how this could be approached, or if there are some libraries out there that do this that i am not aware of?

Comment: Don't optimize prematurely: benchmark whether the decompression actually adds significant overhead or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Zip for this. You would use a compression level of something like "none" or  "store", which just combines the files without compression. [This site](http://help.globalscape.com/help/cutezip2/Compression_levels__effects.htm) enumerates some of them:

> - Maximum - The slowest of the
>     compression options, but the most
>     useful for creating small archives.
> - Normal - The default value.
> - Low - Faster than the default, but
>     less effective.
> - Minimum - Extremely fast
>     compression, but not as efficient as
>     other methods.
> - **None** - Creates a ZIP file but **does
>     not compress it**. File size may be
>     slightly larger if archive is
>     encrypted or made self-extracting.

Here are some C# examples:

- [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ZipStorer.aspx)
- [EggheadCafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/9ce6c242-c14c-4969-9251-af95e4cf320f/zip--unzip-folders-and-f.aspx)

For the unix unaware, this is exactly what `tar` does. When you see .tar.gz files, it's just a bunch of files combined into a `tar` file, and then run through gzip.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [System.IO.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx) namespace.

Quote from MSDN:

> System.IO.Packaging
>
> Provides classes that support storage
>   of multiple data objects in a single
>   container.
>
> Package is an abstract class that can
>   be used to organize objects into a
>   single entity of a defined physical
>   format for portability and efficient
>   access.
>
> A ZIP file is the primary physical
>   format for the Package. Other Package
>   implementations might use other
>   physical formats such as an XML
>   document, a database, or Web service.

You can select different [compression options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.compressionoption.aspx) for your package:

- **NotCompressed** - Compression is turned off.
- **Normal** - Compression is optimized for a balance between size and
  performance.
- **Maximum** - Compression is optimized for
  size.
- **Fast** - Compression is optimized for
  performance.
- **SuperFast** - Compression is optimized for high performance.

Comment: Wow I just learned something... I didn't know this namespace before. +1

Comment: In my experience, the abovementioned OPC APIs turned out to be veeeery slow in not-compressed mode.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps just use a zip with compression set to "none"; SharpZipLib would suffice.

Be careful about assuming that compression is slower, though - it might actually (depending on the scenario) be **quicker** with compression, since you reduce the amount of physical IO and IPC (often a bottleneck), and simply do a bit more CPU work; but you generally have plenty of CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally simple storage files under windows are cabinet files, which do support compression, as well as signing, what zip does not support.

Look out if theres a way to create cabinet files within .net.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to profile first.  Your harddrive is much slower than your cpu or ram.  If the file is sitting on disk reading a smaller, compressed file will take less time than if you read an uncompressed blob.  The difference may well be more than the time it takes to decompress it.

Also the OS may cache the file in memory.  When that happens the harddrive is completely removed from the loop (transparent to you).  That could make the decompression time too costly.

I learned this "technique" when dealing with slow internet connections.  The client needed the data fast and we had cycles to spare.  Sending compressed packets increase the throughput/latency of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I had an additional requirement that the resulting pack file be browsable with standard tools (at least FAR Manager).

So far I've tried:

- *OPC* (Open Packaging Conventions, System.Packaging namespace, ZIP-based, backend for MSO .docx files). Built-in and standard, but quite slow, probably because it actually first copies all data to a temporary location in case it has to be compressed (even if it's not so), and only then writes to the final destination. Unbearably slow. Note that there's also a Windows built-in implementation which is not .NET-based, might be faster but does not span all of the OS versions I have to support.
- *ITSS* (InfoTech Storage System, the backend of CHM files). Built-in in Windows, somewhat standard. Surprisingly, the implementation is incomplete, and it's deadly slow, even slower than OPC.
- *DOC* (COM Compound File Structured Storage, backend for MSO .doc files, .msi files, etc). Built-in in Windows, quite standard. Does not support file names longer than 32 characters, which is a significant drawback in my case. Fast enough on small to middle sizes (totally outruns .NET OPC impl), but has some scalability issues when it goes up to gigabytes.

Various ZIP implementations are still to be tested.